# How to overlay current location on image using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, location

Is there a way to get my current location on iphone using phonegap and overlay a marker of that location onto a floor plan? I am able to get my latitude and longitude using:

```
alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude);
```

I don't know how to translate this to a marker and overlay it onto an image. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

using compass api + geolocation api.
e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var watchID = null;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    startWatch();
}

function startWatch() {
    var options = { frequency: 1000 };
    watchID = navigator.compass.watchHeading(onSuccess, onError, options);
}

/*
function stopWatch() {
    if (watchID) {
        navigator.compass.clearWatch(watchID);
        watchID = null;
    }
}*/

function onSuccess(heading) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess2, onError2);
}

function onError(compassError) {
    alert('Compass error: ' + compassError.code);
}

function onSuccess2(heading) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude);    }

// onError: Failed to get the heading
//
function onError2(compassError) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

I used this pattern.